# Page_Load vs OnLoad

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, page-lifecycle

Why `DisplayUsers();` doesn't work?

My base page is:

```
public class adminPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false) { Response.Redirect("~/Account/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/admin"); };
        if (!(User.IsInRole("admin") || User.IsInRole("super user"))) { Response.Redirect("/"); };
    }        
  }
```

my class is

```
public partial class users : adminPage
{ 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                        
        string sName;
        adminGeneralData.GetToolData(2, out sName);
        pageH1.Text = sName;

        DisplayUsers();
    }

    protected void DisplayUsers()
    {
        DataSet ds = userData.GetUsersData();
        userList.DataSource = ds;
        userList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

but `DisplayUsers()` doesn't work,

Comment: I don't really understand the use of UI.Page as baseclass instead of doing a real business logic. This is a web presentation app. All base logic should be separated from the presentation.

Comment: @dingir - give me an example!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you'll need to call the base class's `OnLoad` event to register the `Page_Load` event properly:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false) { Response.Redirect("~/Account/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/admin"); };
    if (!(User.IsInRole("admin") || User.IsInRole("super user"))) { Response.Redirect("/"); };

    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

Here are a couple of good reads:

- [OnLoad vs. Page_Load vs. Load event](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2008/03/24/onload-vs-page-load-vs-load-event.aspx)
- [When creating a web control should you override OnLoad or implement Page_Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147033/when-creating-a-web-control-should-you-override-onload-or-implement-page-load)

Answer (score 4):

According to [Performance Tips and Tricks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973839.aspx#dotnetperftips_topic4) in .NET Applications:

> Avoid the Autoeventwireup Feature
>
> Instead of relying on autoeventwireup, override the events from Page. For example, **instead of writing a Page_Load() method, try overloading the public void OnLoad()** method. This allows the run time from having to do a CreateDelegate() for every page.

Answer (score 1):

In the code executed, there is no difference, but

- `AutoEventWireup` should be enabled (usually in markup) for each page
- `Page_Load` (and [other events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#additional_page_life_cycle_considerations) like this) uses automatic events subscription [mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479007.aspx#aspnet-pageobjectmodel_topic3), which uses Reflection, what slightly hits performance

I personally recommend to override `OnLoad()`, just don't forget to call `base`.