# why base.onload(e) needed for custom page base class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page base class (.NET4):

```
public class SitePageBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```

And derived class

```
public partial class WebsitePage : SitePageBase
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // some processing
    }
}
```

I checked the "Page_Load" in derived class only works if the "base.OnLoad(e)" is there on the base class's OnLoad event handler. Otherwise the "Page_Load" in derived class not get fired at all.

Can any one tell me, why this is happening?

P.S. The AutoEventWireup is set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are overriding the behaviour of the base class, and if you don't call `base.OnLoad(e)` then the base class will not continue it's implementation (in this case to raise the `Load` event)

In your case, if your not doing anything in `OnLoad` you can remove the method all together, or as i do remove `Page_Load` and do your load login in the overridden `OnLoad`

These are worth a read

- [onload vs page load](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2008/03/24/onload-vs-page-load-vs-load-event.aspx)
- [When creating a web control should you override OnLoad or implement Page_Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147033/when-creating-a-web-control-should-you-override-onload-or-implement-page-load)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am not really doing anything there. so just removed it from the base class. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Clearly it's the base's `OnLoad` function that raises the `Load` event. If you don't call the base's `OnLoad` function, the `Load` event doesn't get raised, and your `Page_Load` event handler never gets invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Because the base implementation of the OnLoad method fires the event that is handled by Page_Load

Answer (score 0):

Typically the base version of an `On<Event>` looks a little bit like this:

```
protected virtual void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
   if(Loaded != null)
      Loaded(this, e);
}
```

So in other words, the base member is the one that actually fires the event.

Answer (score 0):

set the AutoEventWireup to false, that solved the problem for me :)